# How to detect a custom Crossbow in mainhand?

Tags: java, events, plugins, minecraft, projectile

I am trying to detect the crossbow in the players hand (it is a cutom item), but only the bow (also a custom item) seems to be working the way I have it set up right now. Only the bow will show "fire" (and run the code properly) when I test each item.

```
    @EventHandler
public void playerBowShoot(EntityShootBowEvent e) {
    Entity entity = e.getEntity();
    Entity arrow = e.getProjectile();
    if (entity.getType().equals(EntityType.PLAYER)) {
        Player p = (Player) entity;
        if (p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().equals(Weapons.crossbow.getItemMeta())) {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage("fire");
            arrow.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(100.0D));
        }
        if (p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().equals(Weapons.bow.getItemMeta())) {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage("fire");
            arrow.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(100.0D));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work" ?

Comment: oh, i see , it does detect it, but it doesn't run my code propery.

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the item meta to check the type, but `getType()` :

```
@EventHandler
public void playerBowShoot(EntityShootBowEvent e) {
    Entity entity = e.getEntity();
    Entity arrow = e.getProjectile();
    if (entity instanceof Player) {
        Player p = (Player) entity;
        ItemStack hand = p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand();
        if(hand == null) { // nothing in hand
        }  else if (hand.getType().equals(Material.CROSSBOW) && hand.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(theNameOfTheCrossbow)) { // it's a crossbow
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage("fire");
            arrow.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(100.0D));
        }
    }
}
```

To check if it's the good item, you can:

- Just check the type if you want to apply to all items
- Check for custom names/lores/enchants etc...
- Check is similar. Can't be used if the item can be damaged (for example with a sword with durability) or you should copy item, set same durability to check both with `firstItem.isSimilar(secondItem)`

Comment: My problem though is that, these are custom items, I do not want any old crossbow to trigger this code, only the custom one. And I also have two custom crossbows, each does something different, so I cannot just lump them all together.

Comment: You can use `item.isSimilar` or check for item meta, let me update my answer